# How to save plot to new Folder

Tags: python, matplotlib, pathlib

I would like to save my matplotlib plot to the new generated Folder.
I just dont get it to save my plot to this path...

This is my Code so far:

```
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%m_%d_%Y, %H_%M_%S")
dir_name = "Messdaten " + current_time

os.mkdir(dir_name)

my_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    
save_path = my_path + "\\" + dir_name

path = Path(save_path)

plt.savefig(path)
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use os module:

```
import os
my_path = os.path.abspath(__file__) # Figures out the absolute path 
fig.savefig(my_path + '/Sub Directory/graph.png')
```

or:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
results_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'Results/')
sample_file_name = "sample"

os.makedirs(results_dir, exist_ok=True)
plt.savefig(os.path.join(results_dir, sample_file_name))
```

Comment: the first solution just takes the path where the skript is running, but not the folder path, where the skript is inside

Comment: try the second one @Daniel

Comment: Using `join` is better. So, in the 2nd example, it should also be `plt.savefig(join(results_dir, ...))`. Also, you can use `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)` to get rid of the `if`.

Comment: Thats working pretty well! Thank you!